# Highcharts: dateTime in milliseconds is not recognized

Tags: javascript, datetime, highcharts

I have a highcharts graph consisting of 3 different plot lines. Y axis is a number format, X axis is a dateTime. The plots are being displayed properly but the labels on X show '00:00:00' and the tooltip shows the 1-st of January 1970.

Here's my code for initialising the chart:

```
Co2Chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'co2-graph',
            type: 'spline',
            animation: Highcharts.svg,
            marginRight: 10,
            events: {
                load: function () {
                    updateData();
                    setInterval(updateData, 5000);
                }
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: ''
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            tickPixelInterval: 150,
            labels: {
                formatter: function () {
                    return Highcharts.dateFormat('%H:%M:%S', this.value);
                }
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'CO2, ppm'
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1
            },{
                value: 1,
                width: 1
            },{
                value: 2,
                width: 1
            }]
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function () {
                return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
                    Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', this.x) + '<br/>' +
                    Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2);
            }
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: true
        },
        plotOptions: {
            spline: {
                marker: {
                    enabled: false
                }
            }
        },
        exporting: {
            enabled: false
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Master',
            data: []
        },
        {
            name: 'Slave 1',
            data: []
        },
        {
            name: 'Slave 2',
            data: []
        }]
    });
```

This one pushes data:

```
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
                var time = Date.parse(array[i]["dateTime"]);
                Co2Chart.series[0].addPoint(array[i]["masterCo2"], time);
                Co2Chart.series[1].addPoint(array[i]["slave1Co2"], time);
                Co2Chart.series[2].addPoint(array[i]["slave2Co2"], time);
}
```

DateTime string that is passed to the `Date.parse` looks like this `2016-03-28 22:47:49`. And in milliseconds – `1459198069000`

Any ideas why it's not showing?

[image: graph example]

Comment: You're sure "this.value" is what you expect it to be?

Comment: Don't use the Date constructor (or Date.parse, they are equivalent) to parse strings, it is inconsistent and unreliable. Parsing of a string in the format 2016-03-28 22:47:49 is entirely implementation dependent.

Comment: @RobG How do I turn a dateTime string into a highcharts acceptable format without parsing it using JS' Date?

Comment: There are various libraries that contain parsers (moment.js is one but it's probably overkill for this) or just write a [*small function*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9852224/parse-date-in-ie/9852450#9852450) yourself. A generic parser is pretty simple, see [*String date to javascript date: Parse date*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13230360/string-date-to-javascript-date-parse-date). There are also generic parsers and formatters, e.g. [*date-format.js*](https://github.com/barbir/js-date-format/blob/master/js/date-format.js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is how you use `addPoint` method:

```
Co2Chart.series[0].addPoint(array[i]["masterCo2"], time);
```

Should be:

```
Co2Chart.series[0].addPoint([time, array[i]["masterCo2"]]);
```

Or:

```
Co2Chart.series[0].addPoint({
  y: array[i]["masterCo2"], 
  x: time
});
```